# How can I logically test the format of another cell in excel

Tags: macos, excel

I know about conditional formatting.  I want to do the test in the opposite direction.

To simplify, I want to essentially do this:

```
if ((Text_Align(A1)='left',"L","R")
```

or

```
if ((Background_Color(A1)="Pink", "Red dominates the background", "Just another blah background")

if ((Fontweight(A1)="Bold", "That was a strong statement", "A cell filled by a bean counter")
```

So far I've not found a function that can do the equivalent of Text_Align -- that is, test what the value of a cell's format.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've tried this before. I wrote functions that tested the formatting. The problem I ran into was when the formatting changes it doesn't trigger the calculate event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get some information about the cell like format etc using the CELL function e.g. :

```
=CELL("format", H2)
```

This supports a number of other arguments instead of format defined [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx).

However, if the options for this function do not return what you need then you may need to use VBA as proposed in Bathsheba's answer.

Comment: +1, better than my answer if it's sufficient for your needs. Note that CELL is a volatile function.

Comment: -1 This doesn't offer ***ANY*** functionality the OP is looking for, Color only returns if a cell has a color or not (he is looking to test for specific colors), and format only return the cell's format, not any actual formatting of what in the cell (it says that it is a number or date, but not bold underline or italic).

Comment: Actually CELL fits my needs.  It can pick up the left,right, centered, and it can pick up whether it's a number or currency.  It can also pick up text color if not background color.  I can modify my formatting to include items it does pick up.  This is by far the easier answer.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford How did you use the `Cell` function to return the alignment?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in VBA. Here's some prototype code:

```
Public Function test(ByVal rng As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Select Case rng.HorizontalAlignment
    Case xlLeft
        test = "L"
    Case xlRight
        test = "R"
    Case Else
        test = "?"
    End Select

End Function
```

Note the line `Application.Volatile`. This sets the function as *volatile*. It tells VBA that the function return value is not purely a function of the input cell value: formatting changes do not trigger recalculation. Having changed some formatting, use F9 to recalculate the workbook.

Comment: As stated in comments, this will not update when the formatting changes.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Marking the function as volatile goes some way to help.

Comment: You could use volatile. Then recalculate on selection_change. It would slow down your file quite a bit especially if it was of any size. But it would be a little bit better.

Comment: @Bigtree But if you have to do all of that you mine as well use the built in function of Excel's XL4 Macros, that have all of these macros already written, why rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides using VBA Macros, is to use the built in XL4 macros, you can find more infroamtion [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q128185&ID=KB;EN-US;Q128185&FR=1). In that you will find a function from the XL4 Macros, called `Get.Cell` function to return Many aspects of a cell.

***NOTES:*** You **DO NOT** need to download the above file for this to work you can just follow my below directions, but that file contains many more functions and information. Also this method still will not update when only the format of a cell is changed so this will not be any more accurate then running Volatile macros, Although it does save you the need to write all the Macros. It *WILL* update every time the worksheet recalculates, just like will a Volatile Sub/Macro/Function.

When you download the file it will explain in more detail everything inside of the functions.

But the catch is you cannot call `Get.Cell` from the worksheet, but you can call it from a named range. So you have to use it as follows

1. Open the Name Manager
2. Type in the Range name as Text_Align
3. Type this formula in 
   `=GET.CELL(8,OFFSET(ACTIVE.CELL(),0,-1))`
4. Click OK

Now any cell that you type in `=Text_Align`, it will return the cell that is One cell to the left of the cell you enter the formula in, You can modify the above formula to refer to any reference you need.

So with the above if i type `=Text_Align` in cell `B1` it will return the information about `A1`'s horizontal alignment. It will return the following options:

```
    1 = General 
    2 = Left 
    3 = Center 
    4 = Right 
    5 = Fill
    6 = Justify
    7 = Center across cells
```

Below is some of the information in the above linked MacroFun help file I have only added information that pertains to what you have stated in your question that you need:

```
Returns information about the formatting, location, or contents of a cell. Use GET.CELL in a macro whose behavior is determined by the status of a particular cell.

Syntax

GET.CELL(type_num, reference)
Type_num    is a number that specifies what type of cell information you want. The following list shows the possible values of type_num and the corresponding results.

Type_num    Returns

8   Number indicating the cell's horizontal alignment:
    1 = General 
    2 = Left 
    3 = Center 
    4 = Right 
    5 = Fill
    6 = Justify
    7 = Center across cells

13  Number from 0 to 18, indicating the pattern of the selected cell as displayed in the Patterns tab of the Format Cells dialog box, which appears when you choose the Cells command from the Format menu. If no pattern is selected, returns 0.

18  Name of font, as text.
19  Size of font, in points.

20  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are bold, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE.
21  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are italic, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE.
22  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are underlined, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE.
23  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are struck through, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE.
24  Font color of the first character in the cell, as a number in the range 1 to 56. If font color is automatic, returns 0.
25  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are outlined, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE. Outline font format is not supported by Microsoft Excel for Windows.
26  If all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are shadowed, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE. Shadow font format is not supported by Microsoft Excel for Windows.

38  Shade foreground color as a number in the range 1 to 56. If color is automatic, returns 0.
39  Shade background color as a number in the range 1 to 56. If color is automatic, returns 0.
40  Style of the cell, as text.
42  The horizontal distance, measured in points, from the left edge of the active window to the left edge of the cell. May be a negative number if the window is scrolled beyond the cell.
43  The vertical distance, measured in points, from the top edge of the active window to the top edge of the cell. May be a negative number if the window is scrolled beyond the cell.

44  The horizontal distance, measured in points, from the left edge of the active window to the right edge of the cell. May be a negative number if the window is scrolled beyond the cell.
45  The vertical distance, measured in points, from the top edge of the active window to the bottom edge of the cell. May be a negative number if the window is scrolled beyond the cell.
46  If the cell contains a text note, returns TRUE; otherwise, returns FALSE.
48  If the cells contains a formula, returns TRUE; if a constant, returns FALSE.
50  Number indicating the cell's vertical alignment:
    1 = Top 
    2 = Center 
    3 = Bottom 
    4 = Justified
51  Number indicating the cell's vertical orientation:
    0 = Horizontal
    1 = Vertical
    2 = Upward
    3 = Downward

57  Returns TRUE if all the characters in the cell, or only the first character, are  formatted with a superscript font; otherwise, returns FALSE.
58  Returns the font style as text of all the characters in the cell, or only the first character as displayed in the Font tab of the Format Cells dialog box: for example, "Bold Italic".
59  Returns the number for the underline style:
    1 = none
    2 = single
    3 = double
    4 = single accounting
    5 = double accounting

60  Returns TRUE if all the characters in the cell, or only the first characrter, are formatted with a subscript font; otherwise, it returns FALSE.
63  Returns the fill (background) color of the cell.
64  Returns the pattern (foreground) color of the cell.
65  Returns TRUE if the Add Indent alignment option is on (Far East versions of Microsoft Excel only); otherwise, it returns FALSE.
```

***NOTES***

```
Reference    is a cell or a range of cells from which you want information.

If reference is a range of cells, the cell in the upper-left corner of the first range in reference is used.
    If reference is omitted, the active cell is assumed.
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to update with format changes.

Comment: @Bigtree As I stated in the first ***NOTES:*** portion of my answer `Also this method still will not update when only the format of a cell is changed so this will not be any more accurate then running Volatile macros, Although it does save you the need to write all the Macros. It WILL update every time the worksheet recalculates, just like will a Volatile Sub/Macro/Function.` , My earlier comment was in regards to if you are going to use a Selection change event to recalculate the worksheet anyways, using these built in function will at least save you the time of writing the macros yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
=CELL("prefix",A1)

According to the documentation, prefix gives you:

"prefix"
Text value corresponding to the "label prefix" of the cell. Returns single quotation mark (') if the cell contains left-aligned text, double quotation mark (") if the cell contains right-aligned text, caret (^) if the cell contains centered text, backslash () if the cell contains fill-aligned text, and empty text ("") if the cell contains anything else.

So the answer to yours is:

```
=IF(CELL("prefix",A1)=CHAR(34),"R",IF(CELL("prefix",A1)="'","L","?"))
```